# Entity Framework target file missing from build source in Azure pipeline

Tags: entity-framework-core, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml

I'm trying to add a step to my pipeline that will create the Entity Framework migration file.  The command is very straight forward but it keeps erring for a missing `csproj.EntityFrameworkCore.targets` file.  I checked the location `D:\a\1\s\HR Taxonomy Change Management\obj\` and that file is indeed missing.  Here is the YAML step and the error message.

```
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: 'Generate EF SQL Script'
  inputs:
    command: 'custom'
    custom: 'ef'
    arguments: 'migrations script --project "$(Build.SourcesDirectory)\HR Taxonomy Change Management"\*.csproj --output $(build.artifactStagingDirectory)\script.sql  --idempotent'
```

```
Task         : .NET Core
Description  : Build, test, package, or publish a dotnet application, or run a custom dotnet command
Version      : 2.232.0
Author       : Microsoft Corporation
Help         : https://docs.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/build/dotnet-core-cli
==============================================================================
C:\Windows\system32\chcp.com 65001
Active code page: 65001
Info: .NET Core SDK/runtime 2.2 and 3.0 are now End of Life(EOL) and have been removed from all hosted agents. If you're using these SDK/runtimes on hosted agents, kindly upgrade to newer versions which are not EOL, or else use UseDotNet task to install the required version.
"C:\Program Files\dotnet\dotnet.exe" ef migrations script --project "D:\a\1\s\HR Taxonomy Change Management\*.csproj" --output D:\a\1\a\script.sql --idempotent
System.IO.IOException: The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect. : 'D:\a\1\s\HR Taxonomy Change Management\obj\*.csproj.EntityFrameworkCore.targets'
   at Microsoft.Win32.SafeHandles.SafeFileHandle.CreateFile(String fullPath, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, FileOptions options)
   at Microsoft.Win32.SafeHandles.SafeFileHandle.Open(String fullPath, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, FileOptions options, Int64 preallocationSize)
   at System.IO.Strategies.OSFileStreamStrategy..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, FileOptions options, Int64 preallocationSize)
   at System.IO.Strategies.FileStreamHelpers.ChooseStrategyCore(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, FileOptions options, Int64 preallocationSize)
   at System.IO.Strategies.FileStreamHelpers.ChooseStrategy(FileStream fileStream, String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, Int64 preallocationSize)
   at System.IO.File.OpenWrite(String path)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.Project.FromFile(String file, String buildExtensionsDir, String framework, String configuration, String runtime)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.RootCommand.Execute(String[] _)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.Commands.CommandBase.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<Configure>b__0(String[] args)
   at Microsoft.DotNet.Cli.CommandLine.CommandLineApplication.Execute(String[] args)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.Program.Main(String[] args)
The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect. : 'D:\a\1\s\HR Taxonomy Change Management\obj\*.csproj.EntityFrameworkCore.targets'
##[error]Error: The process 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\dotnet.exe' failed with exit code 1
Info: Azure Pipelines hosted agents have been updated and now contain .Net 5.x SDK/Runtime along with the older .Net Core version which are currently lts. Unless you have locked down a SDK version for your project(s), 5.x SDK might be picked up which might have breaking behavior as compared to previous versions. You can learn more about the breaking changes here: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/ and https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/compatibility/ . To learn about more such changes and troubleshoot, refer here: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/build/dotnet-core-cli?view=azure-devops#troubleshooting
##[error]Dotnet command failed with non-zero exit code on the following projects : [ '' ]
Finishing: Generate EF SQL Script
```

When I look at the same location in my repo the `obj` folder contains the file in question
[image]

The other `.targets` file is on the build agent as well as the `.json` file but not the `EntityFrameworkCore.targets`.

Here is the full YAML file.  I've tried both the `MSBuild@1` task and the `VSBuild@1` task.

```
# ASP.NET Core (.NET Framework)
# Build and test ASP.NET Core projects targeting the full .NET Framework.
# Add steps that publish symbols, save build artifacts, and more:
# https://docs.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/languages/dotnet-core

trigger:
- master

pool:
  vmImage: 'windows-latest'

variables:
  solution: '**/*.sln'
  buildPlatform: 'Any CPU'
  buildConfiguration: 'Release'

steps:
- task: NuGetToolInstaller@1
    
- task: NuGetCommand@2
  displayName: Nuget Restore
  inputs:
    command: 'restore'
    restoreSolution: '$(solution)'
    feedsToUse: 'select'
    vstsFeed: '33581106-1fd6-4092-9693-a20196c22142/53f90c9a-62a2-49cc-91c6-9ae04c4ca4fd'

- task: CmdLine@2
  displayName: 'dir D:/a/1/s/.git/'
  inputs:
    script: 
      'dir $(Build.SourcesDirectory)\.git\'


# - task: VSBuild@1
#   displayName: 'Build Solution'
#   inputs:
#     solution: '$(solution)'
#     # msbuildArgs: '/p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:WebPublishMethod=Package /p:PackageAsSingleFile=true /p:SkipInvalidConfigurations=true /p:DesktopBuildPackageLocation="$(build.artifactStagingDirectory)\WebApp.zip" /p:DeployIisAppPath="Default Web Site"'
#     platform: '$(buildPlatform)'
#     configuration: '$(buildConfiguration)'

- task: MSBuild@1
  inputs:
    solution: '**/*.sln'
    platform: '$(buildPlatform)'

- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: 'Install EF tool'
  inputs:
    command: 'custom'
    custom: 'tool'
    arguments: 'install dotnet-ef --global --version 7.0.5'
    workingDirectory: '$(Agent.BuildDirectory)'

- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: 'Generate EF SQL Script'
  inputs:
    command: 'custom'
    custom: 'ef'
    arguments: 'migrations script --project "$(Build.SourcesDirectory)\HR Taxonomy Change Management"\*.csproj --output $(build.artifactStagingDirectory)\script.sql  --idempotent'

- task: VSTest@2
  displayName: 'Running Unit Tests'
  inputs:
    platform: '$(buildPlatform)'
    configuration: '$(buildConfiguration)'

- task: SqlAzureDacpacDeployment@1
  displayName: 'Update Database'
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: 'HR Data Governance (2442165c-339d-4e83-a443-a6583c372938)'
    AuthenticationType: 'servicePrincipal'
    ServerName: 'hrchangemanagement'
    DatabaseName: 'hrchangemanagement'
    deployType: 'SqlTask'
    SqlFile: '$(build.artifactStagingDirectory)\obj\script.sql'

# - task: AzureRmWebAppDeployment@4
#   inputs:
#     ConnectionType: 'AzureRM'
#     azureSubscription: 'HR Data Governance (2442165c-339d-4e83-a443-a6583c372938)'
#     appType: 'webApp'
#     WebAppName: 'HRTaxonomyChangeManagement'
#     packageForLinux: '$(build.artifactStagingDirectory)/**/*.zip'

# - task: TSAUpload@2
#   inputs:
#     GdnPublishTsaOnboard: true
#     GdnPublishTsaConfigFile: '**/*'
```

Comment: Hi there, may I know if the targets file should be downloaded with `nuget restore` command or generated when building the solution with VS? If in your local machine to restore and build the solution, will it generate the targets file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Test the same YAML sample to execute dotnet ef migrations script, I can reproduce the same issue.

[image]

When you use the wildcard `*` in the dotnet ef command, it seems that it cannot find the csproj(`HR Taxonomy Change Management.csproj`) file and instead reads it directly into a string(`*.csproj`).

To solve this issue, you can hardcode the csproj project name in the dotnet ef comamnd.

For example: `--project "$(Build.SourcesDirectory)\HR Taxonomy Change Management"\"HR Taxonomy Change Management.csproj"`

```
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: 'Generate EF SQL Script'
  inputs:
    command: 'custom'
    custom: 'ef'
    arguments: 'migrations script --project "$(Build.SourcesDirectory)\HR Taxonomy Change Management"\"HR Taxonomy Change Management.csproj" --output $(build.artifactStagingDirectory)\script.sql  --idempotent'
```